# Tying/binding Eclipse Commands to a swt button

Tags: eclipse, command, swt

In Eclipse you can use menu contributions to add toolbar buttons and menus that will call a command.  Is there any way to do this to normal swt buttons, apart from programmatically calling the command onclick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) getSite()
                .getService(IHandlerService.class);
        try {
            handlerService.executeCommand("my command id", null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("command with id \"my command id\" not found");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Other way to get the handle service.                                                  IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to listen for the button event and the invoke the command programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandContributionItems in a View or Wizard like that:

```
CommandContributionItemParameter param = new CommandContributionItemParameter(getSite(),
            "myCommand", "com.voo.myCommand", CommandContributionItem.STYLE_PUSH);
param.label = "My Label";
CommandContributionItem item = new CommandContributionItem(param);
item.fill(parent);
```